# Fedora 30 boot freeze - Failed to load SELinux policy

Tags: linux, fedora, selinux

Updated Fedora 30 (workstation) via CLI

```
sudo dnf upgrade -y
```

everything ok, updates downloaded and installed.

SELinux configuration file is set as follows:

```
SELINUX = disabled
```

Then reboot. System freeze at

```
Failed to load SELinux policy
```

How to solve?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what fixed the issue:

On the boot menu, select a boot option and choose `e` to edit.

Add `selinux = 0` to line of main command.

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to start. (Note: this not persists: at the next reboot, this parameter is not saved)

The system boot. Open a terminal and edit /etc/selinux/conf

Restore `SELINUX = disabled` (found `SELINUX = enforcing` again after reboot).

After the next reboot, SELinux is actually disabled and configuration persists.